# could not find member logo (swift, parse)

Tags: ios, swift, mobile, parse-platform

```
if (PFUser.currentUser() == nil){

        self.loginViewController.fields = PFLogInFields.UsernameAndPassword | PFLogInFields.LogInButton | PFLogInFields.SignUpButton | PFLogInFields.PasswordForgotten | PFLogInFields.DismissButton

        var logInLogoTitle = UILabel()
        logInLogoTitle.text = "Test"

        self.logInViewController.logInView.logo = logInLogoTitle

        self.loginViewController.delegate = self

        var signUpLogoTitle = UILabel()
        signUpLogoTitle.text = "Test"

        self.signUpViewController.signUpView?.logo = signUpLogoTitle

        self.signUpViewController.delegate = self

        self.loginViewController.signUpController = self.signUpViewController
    }
```

Getting a could not find member "logo" error @ line 5, any help would be great. Parse was imported and everything

Answer (score 0):

I think its because you need a UIView like this: `self.logInView.logo = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "logoReport"))`